# How to filter API Response to include/exclude some data from TableView in Swift

Tags: json, swift, api

I'm trying to exclude some data I'm receiving from API response,

API Response:

```
{"status":"ok","answer":[{
                    address = Newyork;
                    comments = test;
                    "contact_name" = "ios@ios.com";
                    status = "4";
                    },
                    {
                    address = Ohio;
                    comments = test;
                    "contact_name" = "ios@ios.com";
                    "status" = "3";
                    },
                    {
                    address = cityname;
                    comments = test;
                    "contact_name" = "ios@ios.com";
                    status = "3";
                    },
                    {
                    address = Washington;
                    comments = test;
                    "contact_name" = "ios@ios.com";
                    status = "4";
      }
      )
      )
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, to filter this response, and view only the orders that have status "4" in TableView.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
func getOrdersHistory() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let headers = [
            "content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "dded3e97-77a5-5632-93b7-dec77d26ba99"
        ]

        let user  = CoreDataFetcher().returnUser()
        let email = user.email!

        let postData = NSMutableData(data: "data={\"email\":\"\(email)\",\"type_id\":\"2\"}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://www.someApi/Orders")! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)

        request.httpMethod          = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody            = postData as Data

        let session  = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                if let dataNew = data, let responseString = String(data: dataNew, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(responseString)


                    let dict = self.convertToDictionary(text: responseString)
                    print(dict?["answer"] as Any)
                    self.responseArray = (dict?["answer"] as! NSArray) as! [ConfirmedOrders.JSONDictionary]
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }


                }

            }

        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}

func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This way, I'm getting in TableView, regardless of their status, 
Can anyone help please?

Comment: Do not use `NSMutableURLRequest`, `NSMutableData`, `NSArray` and `NSURL` in Swift. Use the native equivalents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your dataset and using pure Swift arrays and dictionaries, you can simply filter like so:

```
func getConfirmedOrders(in dict: [String:Any]) -> [[String:Any]] {
    guard
        let answers = dict["answer"] as? [[String:Any]]
        else { print("Answer key not present"); return [] }
    
    //Your basic filter operation
    let filtered = answers.filter { (answer) -> Bool in
        return answer["status"] as? String == "4"
    }
    
    return filtered
}
```

It's just about proper type casting and then applying the `filter` operation on it.

Simply using it like so:

```
self.responseArray = self.getConfirmedOrders(in: dict)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

However, I see that your `responseArray` is of type `[ConfirmedOrders.JSONDictionary]`.
So either change `getConfirmedOrders(from:)` to return `[ConfirmedOrders.JSONDictionary]` or change your `responseArray` to be of type `[[String:Any]]`.

---

#### Playground Example

```
let jsonString = """
{"status":"ok","answer":[{"address":"Newyork","comments":"test","contact_name":"ios@ios.com","status":"4"},{"address":"Ohio","comments":"test","contact_name":"ios@ios.com","status":"3"},{"address":"cityname","comments":"test","contact_name":"ios@ios.com","status":"3"},{"address":"Washington","comments":"test","contact_name":"ios@ios.com","status":"4"}]}
"""

if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        //basically what you have in `convertToDictionary(text:)`
        let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]

        let filtered = getConfirmedOrders(in: dict)
        print(filtered)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

---

#### Suggestions:

1. Use Codable models instead of Swift array and dictionary
2. Use Swift `Array` instead of `NSArray`, and similarly use Swift Dictionary instead of `NSDictionary`

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
do {

    let dec = JSONDecoder()
    dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let res = try dec.decode(Root.self, from: data)
     // here filter like e.x
     let filtered = res.answer.filter { $0.status == "4" }
}
catch{
    print(error)
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let status: String
    let answer: [Answer]
}

struct Answer: Codable {
    let address, comments, contactName, status: String
}
```

---

If you need to git rid of `Root` then do

```
do {

    guard let data = data else { return }
    let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options: []) as! [String:Any]
    let dataAns = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:dic["answer"]!, options: [])

    let dec = JSONDecoder()
    dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let res = try dec.decode([Answer].self, from: dataAns)
     // here filter like e.x
     let filtered = res.filter { $0.status == "4" }
}
catch{
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually worked. but I'm having troubles fetching the filtered data in the tableView and getting the below error in console When trying to get this value from response: "order_speciality" = "\U041a\U043e\U043d";

keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "order_service", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "answer", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"order_service\", intValue: nil) (\"order_service\")." underlyingError: nil))

Comment: your json has no key `order_service`